# Mongodb Filters between Date in Java

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Please help, I need to filter between dates using java mongodb driver
below is is my Filtering operation however, its failed to select between the date

```
FindIterable<Document> documents = collection
                .find(Filters.and("started", gte("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),   lt("2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z")))
```

Therefore, I want to be about to filter for Date range.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are doing your filter operation on String representation of dates.
You can try the following in order for Spring-data to construct your filter with [$date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#data_date) operator.

```
Instant from = Instant.parse("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
Instant to = Instant.parse("2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z");

FindIterable<Document> documents = collection.find(Filters.and("started", gte(from),lt(to)));
```

Comment: this method didn't work for me, I am getting symbol gt(instant) cannot be found

Comment: The method is `gte` not `gt`